# How to cancel a Repeating Alarm on app termination (by system or user)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a **setRepeatingAlarm** that is set on user login. The repeating alarm calls a service (but that part is irrelevant to the question).

My problem is, how do I cancel this repeating alarm if Android deems my app unworthy and **terminates** it (to free memory etc) or if the **user swipes off the app from the Recents menu**?

Even if I override onDestroy somewhere, which particular activity of my app will I use it? The user could send the app to background from any activity. Won't it be inefficient to override onDestroy in every activity?